# Indentation standards when writing django Application

Tags: python, django

I am using notepad++ as an editor, and I find that it is easier to follow relations in my code when I use tabs.

1- What is the standard when it comes to putting indentation in the django code (tabs or space)?

2- Do you recommend a code editor other than notepad++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely follow PEP8 (spaces, please!) and also follow the django style guidelines. I suppose it's not an indentation rule, but there are spacing rules and other coding standards.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/#coding-style

It makes sharing code much easier. Whenever I see somebody using camelCase or InitialCaps for methods, attributes, or variables it confuses me and the stackoverflow parser.

Here are some examples from the coding guidelines page:

1. Model names are `InitialCaps`
2. Field definitions are `lower_case`
3. X linebreaks between models
4. Meta classes are defined after the model fields but before methods, with one blank line spacing.
5. Ordering of common methods like `__init__`, `__unicode__`

Answer (score 3):

[Python PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) encourages 4 spaces, no tabs.

Many editors support this, including: [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide), [WingWare](http://www.wingware.com/), and [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) to name just a few.

I should point out that I'm not specifically discouraging you from using tabs, but addressing your question regarding indentation standards.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is going to have a different opinion on text editors, so no point really in asking.

As for the spaces/tabs, python has PEP 8 which gives some general guidelines for coding in Python. The rule here is to indent using 4 spaces.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

As for editors - you might want to try out [Editra](http://editra.org/) (written in python).