# django tutorial poll error list_display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I get an error when following the Django tutorial, when I add a list_display, I get an error. Can somebody figure this out?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Poll
from polls.models import Choice

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Choice
   extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
    (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
  ]
  list_display = ('question', 'pub_date')
  inlines = [ChoiceInline]


admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Comment: seems Indentation error . is it ?

Comment: Exception Type:  IndentationError
Exception Value:  

unexpected indent (admin.py, line 14)

Comment: implementation of class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) is not properly indentated . http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html

Comment: everything is good, when i add a list_display same line for inlines.. ? Should i put somewhere else with tab ?

Comment: which error r u getting now ?

Comment: Exception Type: IndentationError Exception Value: unexpected indent (admin.py, line 14) I added list_display just like inlines = [Choice..]

Comment: Replace all tabs with 4 spaces .

Comment: wow that worked great tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that in Django you cannot mix spaces and tabs

This probably what happens here.

When I started Django with Notepad++ I used to have these problems all the time. I recommend working with Eclipse to edit Django projects - you get an immediate alert when you have indentation issues and the editor handles it gracefully.

See here for addional info:
[Indentation standards when writing django Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318640/indentation-standards-when-writing-django-application)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem following the django tutorials online at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/.
The problem is coming precisely from the 
      inlines = [ChoiceInline]

Just remove all the spaces before this line and everything works fine